# Join 2 tables with classification tag in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a SQL Table in Oracle. I have to join 2 tables (One with ID and other data, second with ID and date in each row, second table is displayed below) but dont want get joined data from the second table but only tag (1 or 0 based on the condition that searching ID has a date between 21/08/01 to 21/08/31).

```py
Table 2 

#    ID      Date            
#    1       21/08/01                           
#    2       21/07/02                           
#    3       21/08/24                        
#    4       21/08/02              
#    5       21/06/03                         
#    6       21/08/05        
#    7       21/08/26                           
#    8       21/08/05
```

My desired output should look like:

```py
Table 1
#    ID      Date   Other data         
#    1       1      ....                     
#    2       0      ....                       
#    3       1      ....                    
#    4       1      ....          
#    5       0      ....                     
#    6       1      ....   
#    7       1      ....                       
#    8       1      ....
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `CASE` to me:

```
with temp_2 as
  (select b.id,
          b.name,
          b.address,
          b.date_column,
          rank() over (partition by b.id order by b.date_column desc) rnk
   from table_2 b
  )  
select 
  a.id,
  a.some_other_column,
  --
  case when b.date_column between date '2021-08-01' and date '2021-08-31' then 1
       else 0
  end as tag
from table_1 a left join temp_2 b on a.id = b.id and b.rnk = 1
```

Comment: I've just posted my code in above comments. Do you see any errors?

Comment: Quite a few of them. Missing coma at the end of line #3, "LEFT OUTER JOIN" (not "JOIN OUTER LEFT"), invalid CASE syntax, invalid date format for DATE literal (must be yyyy-mm-dd), wrongly placed TAG column (not in "AND" but instead of TAG in line #4, OTHER_DATA is most probably not a single column but several columns. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, that work as I desire in my post but I have another problem because in Table 2 I have multiple same ids and I want put only rows with the oldest date per each id in Table1. Do you have any hints for that problem?

Comment: One option is to rank table_2 rows (partitioned per ID) by DATE_COLUMN in descending order, and then fetch only rows whose rank is the "highest" (i.e. is equal to 1). Have a look at edited code.

Comment: Thanks for help. It works but only when there arent multiple the same date for each id. I use the example from Gordon which helps me select only one value per each id. Thank you for your code, its also useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one `id` in `table2`, you can use `left join`:

```
select t`.*,
       (case when t2.date is null then 0 else 1 end) as flag
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.id and
        t2.date between date '2021-08-01' and date '2021-08-31;
```

A more general solution that works for multiple matches in `table2` is `exists`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table2 t2
                          where t2.id = t1.id and
                                t2.date between date '2021-08-01' and date '2021-08-31'
                         )
             then 1 else 0
         end) as flag
from table1 t1
```